# How to find the top value in a column based on another columns active status in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently trying to find the value of a column based on another column having its status set to 'Y'. For example:

Column 1 is number of sales, Column 2 is name, Column 3 is if they are active

I want to be able to have a column show the name of the top seller as long as they have a status of active in column 3. The moment they are inactive in column 3 I would like to have the formula automatically go to the next top seller who is active. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I've tried LARGE, INDEX and MATCH with no luck so far.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you looking to output your desired result? What about just using AutoFilter to first filter out non-active rows and then sort on the Sales column?

Comment: I'm looking to get the highest Name returned. Right now I have it ordered by highest sales and then the name disappears if they are inactive, but I'm struggling to have Excel grab the TOP row that isn't a blank string.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with something like the following:

```
=INDEX(B4:B13, MATCH(MAX(IF(C4:C13="y", A4:A13)), A4:A13, 0))
```

NOTE: After putting in the formula you have to hit SHIFT + CTRL + ENTER on a PC or COMMAND + ENTER on a Mac.  Very important.

This matches your schema where Column A is number of sales, Column B is name, Column C is if they are active.  Obviously my sample data started at row 4 and ended at row 13, you can update accordingly.  Also, you need to update based upon what is in your active column, I have it as a 'y' but it could be 'Yes', or whatever.

For more important you can view this article: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/336139-need-maxifs-function-similar-sumifs.html